# Printing index of [!loop] template directive VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wizard

I am trying to create a custom project wizard in visual studio 2010.

I would like to use the index of the [!loop ] directive to create an enum like so:

```
typedef enum {
  [!loop NUM_OBJECTS]
  OBJECT_[[!output loopIndex],
  [!endloop]
} OBJECTS;
```

Which if NUM_OBJECTS was 3 would print:

```
typedef enum {
  OBJECT_1,
  OBJECT_2,
  OBJECT_3
} OBJECTS;
```

My issue is I don't know how to get the loop index or if getting it is possible.

I've tried searching but there seems to be a limited amount of information on c++ wizards.

Thanks.